# Activity startActivityForResult won't trigger onActivityResult

Tags: android

My Dialog is an Activity with the theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"` defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`. When I start the activity from `Activity A` with:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivityAsDialog.class);   
startActivityForResult(myIntent, REQUEST_DIALOG_ID);
```

I had expected that after calling:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

In `MyActivityAsDialog` would trigger `onActivityResult()` on `Activity A` where I started the Activity.

[image]

Problem is, that `MyActivityAsDialog` is started properly, it is finished properly, but `onActivityResult` from the `Activity A` never gets called.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("EditImageActivity:", "onActivityResult............");
    //code to handle return values comes here
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
        android:name="my.package.MyActivityAsDialog"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_color_dialog" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
        android:parentActivityName="my.package.ActivityA" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="my.package.ActivityA" />
</activity>
```

**MyActivityAsDialog:**

```
public class MyActivityAsDialog extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_color_dialog);      
        setTitle(R.string.colors_content_description);
        //and others setup stuff
    }

    //from layout.xml
    public void cancel(View view) {
         setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
         finish();  
    }
}
```

**myActivityAsDialog** layout (`activity_my_activity_as_dialog.xml`)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ChooseColorDialogActivity" >

     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="cancel"
        android:text="@android:string/cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ActivityA:**

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    public static final int REQUEST_COLOR_DIALOG = 0xDAFFDEBB;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_a);
        //and other setup stuff
    }

    //from layout.xml
    public void selectColor(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivityAsDialog.class);       
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, REQUEST_COLOR_DIALOG);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the launchMode of your MyActivityAsDialog?

Comment: @shuvro none special define (so it's default launch mode)

Comment: Can you add more code

Comment: what´s the value of `REQUEST_DIALOG_ID`?

Comment: Can you add code for MyActivityAsDialog xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xml file of MyActivityAsDialog.class, add below line, in topmost view

```
tools:context=".ActivityA"
```

Comment: i should really use the `ActivityA` for layout of `MyActivityAsDialog`?

Comment: Yes. You should use ActivityA context for MyActivityAsDialog's Layout (XML) file

Comment: uhm ok, but that does not make any changes... i can't believe i'm too stupid to do this easy task, i know i've done it dozend times before...

Comment: This is the problem: REQUEST_COLOR_DIALOG = 0xDAFFDEBB   Please use any other int and check say REQUEST_COLOR_DIALOG = 111

Comment: REQUEST_COLOR_DIALOG = 0xDAFFDEBB **was** the problem!

Comment: Glad to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can try

1. set  `android:launchMode="singleTop"`  for `MyActivityAsDialog`
2. be sure `REQUEST_DIALOG_ID` value is greater than 0

Comment: that does not make any changes... i can't believe i'm too stupid to do this easy task, i know i've done it dozend times before...

Comment: argh - stupid me - i forgot that 0xDAFFDEBB is smaller that zero!!! but @nougat lover gave me the hint on that!

Answer (score 1):

you put ur set result inside the method

```
cancel(View view)
```

Where you call this method. Check this method is properly calling or  not.

Comment: it's called properly - a lot of (not mentioned in this answer) stuff happens, when pressed. the method is define in the layout on a button.